# Programming The Lego Mindstorms T-Rex from EV3 Laboratory

Tags: mindstorms, ev3

I bought the book The Lego Mindstorms EV3 Laboratory fron Daniele Benedettelli. I buid the T-Rex chapter 15 and when I tried to programming the T-Rex (chapter 16) I have a problem. I'm not able to make the last connection when I build the MoveAbsolute block.
I send a picture. Do you know why?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According the book the last input of the MyBlock is a Logic input, instead of a Number (default setting).

Make sure you changed it to Logic and try it again.